# Efficiently parsing text file for datetimes

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, parsing, datetime

I have text files that look like something like

```
<Jun/11 09:14 pm>Information i need to capture1
<Jun/11 09:14 pm> Information i need to capture2

<Jun/11 09:14 pm> Information i need to capture3
<Jun/11 09:14 pm> Information i need to capture4
<Jun/11 09:15 pm> Information i need to capture5
<Jun/11 09:15 pm> Information i need to capture6
```

and two datetimes like

```
15/6/2015-16:27:10  # startDateTime
15/6/2015-17:27:19  # endDateTime
```

I need to grab all the information in the logs between the two datetimes. Currently I make a datetime object from each the two times im searching between.

I then read the file line by line and make a new datetime object that I compare against my start and end time to see if i should grab that line of information. However the files are huge(150MB) and the code can take hours to run(On 100+ files).

The code looks something like

```
f = open(fileToParse, "r")
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue
    lineDateTime = datetime.datetime(lineYear, lineMonth, lineDay, lineHour, lineMin, lineSec)
    if (startDateTime < lineDateTime < endDateTime):
        writeFile.write(line+"\n")
        between = True
    elif(lineDateTime > endDateTime):
        writeFile.write(line+"\n")
        break
    else:
        if between:
            writeFile.write(line+"\n")
```

I want to rewrite this using some more smarts. The files can hold months of information, however I usually only search for about 1 hour to 3 days of data.

Comment: @preezy, can you add a sample of some input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading all the file into memory regardless, just iterate over the file object and break when the date is beyond your upper limit:

```
with  open(fileToParse, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        lineDateTime = datetime.datetime(lineYear, lineMonth, lineDay, lineHour, lineMin, lineSec)
        if startDateTime < lineDateTime < endDateTime:
            writeFile.write(line + "\n")
        elif lineDateTime > endDateTime:
            break
```

Obviously you need to get `lineYear, lineMonth` etc..

using  `f.read().splitlines()` not only reads all the lines into memory so if 5 lines in you are above the upper limit you still have all the lines in memory, you also split the lines so you create a full list of all the lines also.

You could also check  the month/year are correct  and only create datetime objects if you had the correct month/year which would be a lot faster.

If your lines started as above:

```
Jun/11
```

And you wanted Jun/11 then simply `if line.startswith("Jun/11")` and only then start creating datetime objects.

```
with open(fileToParse, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Jun/11"):
            for line in f:
                try:
                    lineDateTime = datetime.datetime...
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                if startDateTime < lineDateTime < endDateTime:
                    writeFile.write(line + "\n")
                elif lineDateTime > endDateTime:
                    break
```

Comment: Do we specifically know that the file contents are sorted by date?  I agree that the `f.read().splitlines()` is a likely cause of inefficiency and is the first easy fix to try.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski,  The OP breaks when `lineDateTime > endDateTime)` so it must be

Comment: Thanks.  I missed that.  I wonder what's better -- reading the whole file into memory and doing a binary search or reading line by line.  My gut says line by line, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There's also the possibility of doing a binary search without reading the whole file into memory.  Seek to half way.  Read until you have a full line.  Evaluate the line and reseek as needed.  Of course this would be much more verbose.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, yes, bisect would probably be worth trying, I suppose it depends on where in the file the interesting parts are.